# Unable to connect to mongodb database via Studio3T with Authentication

Tags: mongodb, authentication, connection, localhost, studio3t

I am using Ubuntu16.04 and i had enabled authorization in mongodb and created user via following.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "ABC",
    pwd: "XYZ",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
);
```

And after restarting mongodb server authorization working fine while connecting to the mongodb via terminal.

```
sudo service mongod restart
mongo -u ABC -p --authenticationDatabase admin
```

But when i am trying to connect to my localhost mongodb database with Studio3T with following

```
Authentication Mode : "Basic (MONGODB-CR or SCRAM-SHA-1)"
username : (ABC)
password : (XYX)
Authentication DB: (admin)
```

I am getting error message as following.

```
Connection failed.

SERVER [localhost:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketWriteException): Exception sending message
|____/ Socket error: Connection reset

Details:
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Connection reset}}]
```

Comment: i also face the same issue on current release: Connection failed.

SERVER [localhost:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketWriteException): Exception sending message
|____/ SSL error: Remote host closed connection during handshake
|_______/ I/O error: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Comment: any solution to this?